# windows10 dual boot showing black screen-UEFI

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 18.04, uefi, windows-10

I have installed Lubuntu18.04. 
I can see both ubuntu and windows option in grub. Ubuntu is getting started fine. However, when I am selecting windows 10- it's showing a window image, then after a few seconds a black screen is appearing and it's just hanging there.

Both windows and ubuntu are set to boot from UEFI.

I have disabled fast boot in windows 10. Moreover, I tried to run the boot repair scripts(output is provided below). However, the issue is still present. Please help!

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VrGfK74ZXv/

Comment: It looks like you have 3 Windows boot options. Did you try all of them?

Comment: Can you directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu. You show many UEFI Windows entries, but only one Windows & the Ubuntu entry look like valid UEFI entries. The others may be BIOS version. I would delete any duplicates. Like this, but on the Windows entries: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2289179&p=13331743#post13331743  You may want to change sda to gpt since your NVMe drive is gpt. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1454252

Comment: Yes- If I change UEFI to windows UEFI in the bios boot menu, then windows is starting fine. The correct 2 grub entry for windows 10 are:Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme0n1p1) and Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi. both are having same problem.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix - yes I have tried all of them.